# Adapter for a spinner makes NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, android-spinner, android-adapter

I made an array list in one of my value's folder, now when i want to adapt it to the spinner by retrieving it from the source folder it says  `NullPointerException`:

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.worker,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Messages in LogCat:

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f090001 at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:527) at com.example.hay.myapplication.UserCreatingActivity.onCreate(UserCreatingActivity‌​.java:46) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:227
```

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: Is the spinner null, as Deepak says post the logcat.

Comment: Added my answer, it is probably related to not using a type for the Array Adapter and the layout type (check my modifications)

Comment: @LucasCrawford Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f090001
            at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:527)
            at com.example.hay.myapplication.UserCreatingActivity.onCreate(UserCreatingActivity.java:46)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:227

Comment: @LucasCrawford <string-array name="worker">

        <item>מנהל</item>
        <item>אחראי משמרת</item>
        <item>צ׳קר</item>
        <item>מלצר</item>
        <item>טבח</item>

    </string-array>

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the ArrayAdapter a type:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.worker, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: It still shows me a nullPointerExeption :
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:214)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:503)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:430)
            at com.example.hay.myapplication.UserCreatingActivity.onCreate(UserCreatingActivity.java:45)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at

Comment: I made another edit. Try that. Also link your R.array.worker

Comment: <string-array name="worker">

        <item>מנהל</item>
        <item>אחראי משמרת</item>
        <item>צ׳קר</item>
        <item>מלצר</item>
        <item>טבח</item>

    </string-array>

Answer (score 0):

Try to flip the two last parameters in `createFromRessource`:

Replace:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.worker,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

By:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.worker);
```

In your code:

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.worker);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have the exception:

```
 `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f090001 at
```

I see that your problem is the last value inside the `createFromResource()` method:

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.worker,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

the last value must be the array:

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.array.worker);
```

Answer (score -1):

change

```
 attr.xml
```

directory

from

```
...\app\src\main\res\values-w820dp
```

to

```
...\app\src\main\res\values
```